# Maximum Principle - Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f$ is holomorphic in the unit disk $D = \{z:|z| < 1\}$ and $f$ is dominated by $e^z$ on the boundary $|z|=1$, that is $|f| \leq |e^z|$. Then how big can $|f(\ln z_o)|$ be for $ \ln z_0 \in D$? Here $\ln z := \log_e(z) + i(arg z + 2\pi n).$ We may assume $f$ extends continuous on the boundary of $D$, if needed.

Isn't this just a direct application of the Maximum Principle? I thought that the obvious answer would be $|f(\ln z_0) \leq |e^{\ln z_0}| =z_0$.

**Addendum:**, lets make $z_ 0 = 1$ to make things easier.

Comment: How do you know $\ln z_0\in D$?

Comment: Let's say that $\ln z_0 \in D$, for simplicity, take $z_0$ to be a real number.

Comment: Take $f(z)= e$. Note that $\max_{|z|=1} |e^z| = e$.

Comment: @copper.hat, so basically I am right?

Comment: Well, what is true is that for all suitable $f$ is that $\sup_{|z|<1}|f(z)| \le e$ and there is some $f$ for which this value is attained.

Comment: @copper.hat, never mind. You trying to say that the maximum actually *is* $e$. Sorry I was too slow.

Comment: No problem at all.